# For every element in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

i have a 3D camera with depth informations for every frame. The depth informations are stored in a 2D-Numpy-Array like this:

```
[[4854 4854 4854 ... 1999 1999    0]
 [4831 4831 4831 ... 1998 1998 1999]
 [4785 4785 4785 ... 1997 1997 1999]
 ...
 [1694 1694 1694 ...  909  908  909]
 [1695 1695 1695 ...  908  907  909]
 [1695 1695 1695 ...  907  906    0]]
```

Now i want to build the average for the first 5 - 10 frames. That is my code so far:

```
   if frame_counter <= frame_fuer_initialen_tiefen:
        new_frame = depth_color_image

        for x in new_frame:
            initiale_tiefen[x] = (initiale_tiefen[x] + new_frame[x])/2
```

Idea is to store the depth_color_image into new_frame and then for every element add up these two numbers on the same position in the array and divide them by two. When the next frame arrives I'll do the same till the frame_counter is higher then frame_fuer_initialen_tiefen (which i can use a number on how many frames i want to add). Problem is i get this error:

"IndexError: index 2058 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0"

Does somebody knew help? Thank you very much

Comment: Can you explain your rationale for taking the average of the previous average and the new frame, rather than the average of all the frames? This gives a very high weightage to later frames and a much lower weightage to earlier frames. If you just want the average of the frames, you need to add all the frames together and then divide by 5 or whatever your number of frames is. Also, what are frame_fuer_initialen_tiefen and initiale_tiefen?

Comment: I don't quite understand your code. Anyway, if one image is 2D and several image are 3D let's say with a shape of `(N,N, nb_images)` you can directly get the mean value by slicing using numpy through : `np.mean(image_stack[:,:,:5])` for the 5 first images for exemple.